# IfModule directive strange behaviour

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

I've configured 3 virtual servers for Apache2 under Centos6. Each server config is wrapped inside `IfModule` directive like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    Listen 15100
    NameVirtualHost *:15100
    <VirtualHost *:15100>
...
</IfModule>
```

2 of 3 servers work fine, but when I try to open the main page of the last server, Apache doesn't seem to listen to its port. I've figured out that if I remove the `IfModule` check from the last server config everything works as expected. All of these directives check if the same module is present - mod_fcgid.c. I can't understand what's wrong with my configs.